# Why SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner?

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, mx-record, reverse-dns

I have set rDNS to [mail.simplyislam.biz](http://mail.simplyislam.biz) for IP 178.32.48.104 with my hosting server and also in DNS control panel.

However, I am still failing [this test](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3Amail.simplyislam.biz&run=toolpage#)

> ***Result:*** SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch Warning - Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner. See attached

But as far as I can see my rDNS for the IP address are both the same: [mail.simplyislam.biz](http://mail.simplyislam.biz)

I am at a loss as to how to fix the issue please ?

Comment: Your server is closing the connection right after the client sends the helo and never sends the helo itself. This is a misconfiguration of your mail server, not in DNS.

Comment: @sebix his DNS configuration is funny anyway ;) Check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner

The SMTP Banner is the response of your mail server for the `ehlo` query. Currently your mail server is closing the connection. That is the reason for the mismatch between rDNS and SMTP banner. Reverse DNS itself is set up correctly, though.

```
# telnet mail.simplyislam.biz 25
Trying 178.32.48.104...
Connected to mail.simplyislam.biz.
Escape character is '^]'.
ehlo example.com
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

---

Having looked a little deeper, your DNS and mail server configuration seems a little messy:

```
> set type=mx
> simplyislam.biz
…
simplyislam.biz MX preference = 0, mail exchanger = mail.simplyislam.com
simplyislam.biz MX preference = 90, mail exchanger = mail.simplyislam.biz

> mail.simplyislam.biz
…
simplyislam.biz MX preference = 0, mail exchanger = mail.simplyislam.com
simplyislam.biz MX preference = 90, mail exchanger = mail.simplyislam.biz

> simplyislam.com
…
simplyislam.com MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = simplyislam.biz
simplyislam.com MX preference = 30, mail exchanger = mail.simplyislam.com
```

Your domain (the part behind the *"@"* in an email address) needs a `MX` record pointing to your mail server:
`simplyislam.biz. 3600 IN MX 10 mail.simplyislam.biz.`

Then you need an `PTR` record pointing your IP address to your mail server, but that does already exist:
`104.48.32.178.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN PTR mail.simplyislam.biz.`

Your mail server address does not need an `MX` record, unless you are expecting emails sent to *"@mail.simplyislam.biz"*.

Of course you need to do the same things for your primary mail server "mail.simplyislam.com".

Answer (score 0):

As of now, MXtoolbox do not show any error while looking up rDNS of IP address 178.32.48.104. rDNS of IP address 178.32.48.104 is set to FQDN mail.simplyislam.biz.

http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3amail.simplyislam.biz&run=toolpage#

Thanks,